How to Create Rounded Gears with Adjustable Wave Angles
I'm trying to create a shape similar to the one in the image below, where the gears have rounded edges and a wavy pattern. I would like to be able to adjust the angle of these 'waves'.
As a beginner in Blender, I think using Geometry Nodes would be the best approach for this.
Here’s an example of the result I’m aiming for:

Any tips or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

It would be great to start by defining "what is the angle of the waves"?

You can cobble up something vaguely similar with Geometry Nodes.


Start with a mesh circle.
Use a Floored Modulo to get a selection of every other vertex using the Index node.
Using a set position node, feed it the above selection of vertex
Using a Mix Vector node, you can mix between the local origin and the position from a Position, crudely simulating scaling the vertex towards the center of the gear, to create the teeth.
Convert the mesh to curve, set the type to Bezier
Use a Fillet Curve to round the tips, make sure to tick the Limit Radius to avoid self intersecting messes.



amazing! +10000
